# Using the MSQL XDEVAPI In Node JS, can I chain multiple calls together?

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, mysql-x-devapi

Example, I'm trying to check to see if a value exists in a table and then if no duplicates exists write the values in the same table, but its not working. Let me know if chaining the calls is possible if not, would I just pass the variable and then do another call to the DB, also I'm having trouble closing the connection to a single session, any help would be appreciated.

```
  mysqlx.getSession({ 
    user: 'robot', 
    password: 'password',
    host: 'localhost:8080',
    port: '33060'
})

    .then (function(session){
var v_table = session.getSchema('nms2019local').getTable('v_table')

for (let k=0; k<s_key.length; k++){
 v_table
.select(['s_key', 'accounts'])
.where('s_key like :accounts')
.bind('s_key',s_key[k])
.execute()
.then(function(s_keyDuplicates, session){
    
    let s_keyDuplicatesCheck = s_keyDuplicates.fetchOne()
    console.log(s_keyDuplicatesCheck)
    if (s_keyDuplicatesCheck === undefined){
        
        for (let n = 0; n<s_key.length; n++){
            return v_table
            .insert(['s_key'])
            .values([s_key[n]])

        }
    }
//     else{
    
//     let s_key_final = [];
//     s_keyDuplicatesArray = s_keyDuplicates.toArray()
//    for (var m in s_key){
//        if(!s_keyDuplicatesArray.includes(s_key[m])) s_key_final.push(s_key[m])
//    } console.log(s_key_final)
//    for (let l = 0; l<s_key_final.length; l++){
//              return v_table
//              .insert(['s_key'])
//              .values([s_key_final[l]]) 
//    }
    
// }
})


}



})


.catch(function(err){
console.log('the following error occured: ' + err.message)

})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What exactly do you mean by chaining? From a quick look, I would say the only problem is that you are not calling `execute()` with `insert()`, and thus, the values are never sent to the server. I'm not sure about the async flow though. Would have to check.

Also, I'm not sure if the `s_key` column is supposed to contain unique values, but if that is the case you are probably better off creating a unique key constraint and using an SQL "upsert" strategy like [`ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html).

Disclaimer: I'm the lead developer of the MySQL X DevAPI Connector for Node.js

Comment: Thank you, yes they are unique values.   And the answer was so simple, just add the execute and it worked.